# Async-await was never awaited in function call

Tags: python, async-await

When I try to call the function 'check', it couldn't be called and run into an error.

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Acc.check' was never awaited

```py
import json, random

# -- Functions --
async def read():
    with open("data.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

# -- Commands --
class Acc:
    async def check():
        data = await read()

        user = data.keys()

        if str(user) not in data:
            numbers = "012345689"
            
            user = "".join(random.sample(numbers, 8))

            data[str(user)] = {}

            with open("data.json", "w") as f:
                json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

Acc.check()
```

Comment: Added the python tag... quite essential here...

Comment: json module isn't async based so it will not work how you're expecting, also, the reason it is saying that is because you are calling Acc.check() like a normal function, to fix this, run it in an event loop. asyncio.run(Acc.check()) will work for newer python versions 3.8+

Answer (score 2):

The `Acc.check()` returns a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) object. You should run it in an event-loop:

```py
import asyncio

# your codes
...

asyncio.run(Acc.check())
```